# How do I make a line connect between a certain point on the screen, to the user's finger location?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, touch, line

I'm making a game, but haven't been able to figure this out yet.

So, there's a little zappy ball of electricity at the bottom of the screen, and I want to make it so that – when you touch the screen – it makes a line of electricity, and connects it between the zappy ball and your finger. When you move your finger, the line shrinks or enlarges to fit the distance between the two.

Think of it like those electricity balls in real life. You touch your finger to it, the electricity redirects to your finger. When you move your finger, the line of electricity move with it, so it can find the electricity in your finger and pair up with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `SKShapeNode` to draw a line between two points. Create an `SKShapeNode` in `touchesBegan`. You can then modify its path based on `touch location` in `touchesMoved`.

```
var currentLine : SKShapeNode!

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch?
    if let pointOfTouch = touch?.locationInNode(self) {
        currentLine = SKShapeNode()
        let pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, 100.0, 100.0); // Change to zap
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, pointOfTouch.x, pointOfTouch.y);
        currentLine.path = pathToDraw
        self.addChild(currentLine)
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch?
    if let pointOfTouch = touch?.locationInNode(self) {
        let pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, 100.0, 100.0); // Change to zap
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, pointOfTouch.x, pointOfTouch.y);
        currentLine.path = pathToDraw
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes . . . I hadn't even thought of SKShapeNodes yet. Thanks for the little code snippet, rakeshbs!

Comment: I'm still working out your solution and compiling it with others to come up with what I want. I'm sure it'll work fine for me. But, to ease your conscience, I'll let you know for sure pretty soon here :)

Comment: Alright, that worked perfectly. Thanks again for the help, and sorry for a late reply!